# Read and write cookies

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, phpjs

I have a javascript file linked to a PHP page which has a value that needs be saved for when a form is submitted and the page is refreshed.

Is there a simple way to set cookies similar to the method in PHP.

```
setcookie("MovementDate", $MovementDate, time()+3600);
```

Everything I have found is very complex and can't seem to get to work.

Also reading set cookies is currently an issue. From my searches I came up with this method however it's not working.

```
function readCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
```

}

```
var movement = readCookie(MovementDate);
document.write(movement);
```

Comment: If you can use JQuery, these is a simple plugin JQuery Cookie. It's good. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already comfortable with using PHP, you can use [PHPjs](http://phpjs.org/pages/home):

For setting, use the [`setcookie`](http://phpjs.org/functions/setcookie) function.

For reading, use the use the [`runkit_superglobals`](http://phpjs.org/functions/runkit_superglobals) function.  This will give you access to the the `$_COOKIE` superglobal using the exact same methods as PHP.

Example:

```
// Setting
// setcookie uses seconds but the JS Date object returns milliseconds,
// so we need to divide by 1000
setcookie("foo", "bar", (new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 3600);

// Reading
runkit_superglobals();    
alert($_COOKIE["foo"]); // alerts "bar"
```

Comment: @Justin Johnson: And why is that?

Answer (score 2):

When calling readCookie, the argument needs to be a string. Change your second to last line to this:

```
var movement = readCookie("MovementDate");
```